# \textlangle and \textrangle, with kpfonts-otf, not displayed with lualatex but displayed with xelatex

Tags: xetex, pdftex, symbols, luatex, kpfonts

As shown by the following MCE, `\textlangle` and `\textrangle` are correctly displayed with `pdflatex` + `kpfonts` but not with `lualatex` + `kpfonts-otf`.

The latter case is not so unexpected since Daniel Flipo, the maintainer of `kpfonts-otf`, told me these characters are currently missing (he's working on it). But what is strange is these characters are correctly displayed with `xelatex` + `kpfonts-otf`.

Do you know why `xelatex` successfully display them?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifpdftex
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\else
\usepackage{kpfonts-otf}
\fi
\begin{document}
\verb|$\langle\rangle$| $=\langle\rangle$

\verb|\textlangle\textrangle| $=$ \textlangle\textrangle
\end{document}
```

- With `pdflatex`

[image]

- With `xelatex`

[image]

- With `lualatex`

[image]

Comment: I would guess harfbuzz is being clever here (Unicode has "issues" with langle and rangle, let me look...)

Comment: luatex log `Missing character: There is no 〈 (U+2329) in font [KpRoman-Regular.otf]:mode=n`  (U+2329 is deprecated character should be U+27E8, but that doesn't help, looking...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LaTeX's \textlangle and \textrangle insert Unicode codepoints U+2329 and U+232A by default. In your font, these glyphs do not exists, but Unicode codepoints U+3008 and U+3009 are available. According to Unicode data tables, these are canonically equivalent (meaning they "should" always appear exactly the same) to U+2329 and U+232A, so HarfBuzz (used by XeTeX and when explicitly requested by LuaTex) substitutes these. (This is a bit problematic because U+3008 and U+3009 are CJK characters and therefore might be wider in many fonts, but that's not an issue with kpfonts.)

To get the correct glyphs also in LuaTeX you can enable HarfBuzz or change which codepoints LaTeX uses:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifpdftex
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\else
\usepackage{kpfonts-otf}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textlangle}\UnicodeEncodingName{"3008}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textrangle}\UnicodeEncodingName{"3009}
\fi

\begin{document}
\verb|$\langle\rangle$| $=\langle\rangle$
\verb|\textlangle\textrangle| $=$ \textlangle\textrangle
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

The luatex log shows

```
Missing character: There is no 〈 (U+2329) in font [KpRoman-Regular.otf]:mode=n
```

It works in luatex if you use HarfBuzz (like xetex)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifpdftex
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\else
\usepackage{fontspec}
\ifluatex
\defaultfontfeatures{Renderer=HarfBuzz}
\fi
\usepackage{kpfonts-otf}
\fi
\begin{document}

\verb|$\langle\rangle$| $=\langle\rangle$

\verb|\textlangle\textrangle| $=$ \textlangle\textrangle

\end{document}
```

In theory (but apparently not in practice) U+2329 shouldn't be used, it has an unfortunate Unicode normalization to a full width angle bracket in the CJK block and U+27E8 was added specifically to avoid this character.

Comment: I suspect you need Ulrike or Marcel to explain what luaotfload is doing here:-)

Comment: luaotfload is doing "the obvious thing": The font does not have U+2329, therefore it complains that it's missing. The font does have a character in U+3008 though (that's the one in the CJK font) which is picked up by HarfBuzz (because of semi-normalization like behavior).

Comment: @MarcelKrüger ah it's 3008  I assumed it was harfbuzz normalization, I thought it was going to  27E8 but then I couldn't understand why it didn't work if I input that directly.